# Update minicart after adding products programmaticaly

Tags: magento2

I'm adding products programmaticaly in my module. I've created etc/frontend/sections.xml file with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="modextend/cart/addProducts">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

And it's routes.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="modextend" frontName="modextend">
            <module name="Vendor_ModulesExtend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And for some reason minicart isn't updating itself after using my controller. Products are added successfully because I can see them in checkout and cart.

Do you know why isn't it working?

Edit:
I've tried it also by AJAX request:

```
var url = '/modextend/cart/addProducts/products_ids/';
//selectedAccessories is array of products id's
url += selectedAccessories.join(',');

$.ajax(
    url,
    {method: 'post'}
).done(function(res)
{
    console.log(res);
});
```

And its my controller action:

```
$products = $this->getRequest()->getParam('products_ids');
$result = [];

if($products)
{
    $products = explode(',', $products);

    try {
        $this->cart->addProductsByIds($products);
        $this->cart->save();

        $result['success'] = true;
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Selected accessories has been added to your cart.'));
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $result['error'] = true;
        $this->messageManager->addException(
            $e,
            __('%1', $e->getMessage())
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $result['error'] = true;
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('There was an error while adding accessories to your cart.'));
    }
}

$this->getResponse()->representJson(
    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
);
```

Comment: I've tried. Doesn't matter if I use this controller throught AJAX or redirect. It isn't working...

Comment: can u add ur ajax and controller here ? it works fine for me. also u have to wait for a few seconds for the minicart to update and success msg to show up, after the ajax is complete. u can check via firebug about the running process

Comment: Yes, of course. See it in edit

Comment: And what about actions like removing products or updating in cart? Those are done by post request, not ajax, and still minicart is refreshing. So it should be possible, right?

Comment: u r right. if u dig deeper in those actions, u might be able to find a reason, and when u find a solution, pls post it here so other can also know :)

Comment: Definitely, if I'll finish it successfully I will post the answer here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working.

The problem was, that form I was creating in js wasn't appended to body.

Here you have request sended via js:

```
var url = '/modextend/cart/addProducts/';

if(selectedAccessories.length === 0)
{
    return false;
}

var form = $('<form>').attr('action', url).attr('method', 'post');
var input = $('<input type="hidden" name="products_ids" />').val(selectedAccessories.join(','));
input.appendTo(form);

form.appendTo('body').hide().submit();
```

**appendTo('body')** is here critical part.

And in controller standard redirect to cart:

```
$products = $this->getRequest()->getParam('products_ids');
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

if($products)
{
    $products = explode(',', $products);

    try {
        $this->cart->addProductsByIds($products);
        $this->cart->save();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Selected accessories has been added to your cart.'));
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException(
            $e,
            __('%1', $e->getMessage())
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('There was an error while adding accessories to your cart.'));
    }
}

$resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart/index');

return $resultRedirect;
```