# Magento 2: Mini cart product count not updating for current session

Tags: magento2, api, session, mini-cart

I'm using a `live chatbox API` which is integrated into Magento 2.

**The problem is:**
When I add a product from the live chat box, the product counter is not getting updated in the Magento's mini cart. (for the current logged in session)

But when I login to the site in different browsers i.e for a new session, then the mini cart product count is getting incremented.

This is happening only with the chatbox API integration, with default Magento, mini cart updates, but not with this chat box  (I'm not using any module for chatbox, it's only API integration)

Need suggestion on how to debug this counter issue in the mini cart in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create sections.xml inside etc/frontend in your module like below.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="[frontName]/[ActionPath]/[ActionName]">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

It will load that section.

Comment: I went through different links for my problem like: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110472/update-minicart-after-adding-products-programmaticaly/110514#110514  and my doubt is, since i am just using the Chat box API, should i create a separate custom module inheriting the Checkout module?

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, any update on the same? I am using the chatbot as an api, just calling this API, not using any custom module, how do i proceed on this?